# Toggle language on the current page with JSTL or Spring MVC tag

Tags: spring-mvc, jstl

I'm using Spring MVC LocaleChangeInterceptor to handle change of locale. I need 2 simple links to switch the current page between English and French while keeping any existing parameter of the current URL.

The solution I've came up with looks rather ugly. A c:url tag with an empty value to link to the current page and a loop to append any existing parameter except for the language parameter that I don't want to see twice. So the code is as follow.

```
<c:url value="" var="englishURL">
    <c:forEach items="${param}" var="currentParam">
        <c:if test="${currentParam.key != 'siteLanguage'}">
            <c:param name="${currentParam.key}" value="${currentParam.value}"/>
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
    <c:param name="siteLanguage" value="en"/>
</c:url>
<c:url value="" var="frenchURL">
    <c:forEach items="${param}" var="currentParam">
        <c:if test="${currentParam.key != 'siteLanguage'}">
            <c:param name="${currentParam.key}" value="${currentParam.value}"/>
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
    <c:param name="siteLanguage" value="fr"/>
</c:url>
<a href="${englishURL}">English</a> / <a href="${frenchURL}">Français</a>
```

Does someone have a less ugly way to create these links? I know I can create a custom tag to avoid the duplication but I feel that's a very small improvement since I need to declare the tag and all.

Answer (score 2):

Not really less ugly, but atleast some less code duplication

```
<c:forEach var="tuple" items="${fn:split('en,English|fr,Français|nl,Nederlands', '|')}" varStatus="status">
  <c:set var="locale" value="${fn:split(tuple, ',')[0]}"/>
  <c:set var="name" value="${fn:split(tuple, ',')[1]}"/>
  <c:url value="" var="url">
    <c:forEach items="${param}" var="currentParam">
      <c:if test="${currentParam.key != 'changeLocale'}">
        <c:param name="${currentParam.key}" value="${currentParam.value}"/>
      </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
    <c:param name="changeLocale" value="${locale}"/>
  </c:url>
  <a href="${url}">${name}</a>
  <c:if test="${not status.last}"> / </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems like you are appending the siteLanguage param in your url everytime. Is it correct? Why you need to do this? You can save this language change in session or cookie and then everytime you don't need to specify the siteLanguage parameter. Once the language is selected then the language parameter is stored in the session or cookie. And spring will manage the rest of the things itself.

Just specify either SessionLocaleResolver or CookieLocaleResolver along with your LocaleChangeInterceptor. It will do this for you.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: No, I'm already using CookieLocaleResolver. I only specify the siteLanguage param for the links which change the language of the site.

Comment: Okies... Then its a different problem. :-)